Can you use a coin to restore a health segment after you've reached 0?
I haven't managed to find a way to answer this in practice, but I could imagine it working.
Let's say you're on 1 segment of health. You get hit midair (bringing it down to 0), and manage to grab on a coin before landing AND the health meter shattering. A very unlikely situation, but if it occurred, would Mario get his life segment back before he dies? Or will nothing happen and he dies anyways?
If he survives, maybe it would be a niche way to clutch a boss fight...

I think there was something similar in Super Mario World where you could die but in the falling animation use a key to enter a warp still.

Yes, you definitely can.
A Reddit user tested it with a Big Bullet Bill:

You can cheat death in Mario Galaxy if you collect a coin before hitting the ground.


Open the link to see a video proof.
